# If $y=\dfrac {1}{x^{x}}$ then show that $y'' (1)=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=\dfrac {1}{x^x}$ then show that $y'' (1)=0$

My Attempt:

$$y=\dfrac {1}{x^x}$$
Taking $\ln$ on both sides,
$$\ln (y)= \ln \left(\dfrac {1}{x^x}\right)$$
$$\ln (y)=-x.\ln (x)$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$
$$\dfrac {1}{y}\cdot y'=-(1+\ln (x))$$

Comment: What is $y_2(1)$ rather than $y(1)=\frac{1}{1^1}$?  Is it the second derivative?

Comment: @Henry, $y_{2} (1)$ is the second derivative evaluated at $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y(1)=?$

$$-y_1=y(1+\ln x)$$

$y_1(1)=?$

$-y_2=y_1(1+\ln x)+y/x$

$$y_2(1)=-y_1(1)-y(1)=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\frac{1}{x^x}$, then $ln(y)=-xln(x)$, then $y'(x)=-(1+ln(x))y(x)$. Taking a second derivative, we have that $y''(x)=-y'(x)(1+ln(x))-\frac{y(x)}{x}$. Evaluating at $x=1$, we have that $y(1)=1$, $y'(1)=-1$, so that $y''(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

According to your own calculations, $y'(x) = - y(x)(1+ \ln x)$, and, in particular, since $y(1)=1$, you have that $y'(1)=-1$. If you derive again,

$$
y''(x) = (-y(x)(1+ \ln x))'= -y'(x)(1+\ln x)-y(x) \cdot \frac 1x
$$

In particular, $y''(1)=-y'(1)(1+0)-y(1) \cdot 1= 0.$

Answer (score 0):

As $x^x$ is $\exp(x \ln(x))$, we have $y(x) = e ^ {- x \ln(x)}$. It is easy to see that $y$ is indefinitely derivable over $\mathbb{R}^\star_+$.

Thus, $y'(x) = - y(x) (1+ \ln(x))$ and $y''(x) = - \left( y'(x)(1+ \ln(x)) + y(x) \frac{1}{x} \right)$.

We obtain:

$y''(1) = - y'(1) - y(1) $ as $\ln(1) = 0$.

$y(1) = 1$ and $y'(1) = -y(1)(1+\ln(1)) = -1$.

Finally  we can say that $y''(1) =  0$.

Answer (score 0):

One of the results in Theorem 3 of the reference [1] below is
\begin{equation}\label{x-poer-x-thm3-driv}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\bigl[(1+x)^{t(1+x)}\bigr]
=n!(1+x)^{t(1+x)-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^k(1+x)^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{[\ln(1+x)]^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{equation}
Replacing $1+x$ by $x$ in the above formula yields
\begin{equation}\label{x-poer-x-thm3-driv-repl}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\bigl(x^{tx}\bigr)
=n!x^{tx-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^kx^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{equation}
Taking $t=-1$ and $n=2$ in the above formula leads to
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^2}{\operatorname{d}x^2}\bigl(x^{-x}\bigr)
&=\frac{\operatorname{d}^2}{\operatorname{d}x^2}\biggl(\frac1{x^{x}}\biggr)\\
&=\frac{2}{x^{x+2}}\sum_{k=0}^{2}(-1)^k x^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{2-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{2-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}\\
&=\frac{x+x \ln^2x+2 x\ln x-1}{x^{x+1}}\\
&\to 0, \quad x\to1.
\end{align*}

References

1. J. Cao, F. Qi, and W.-S. Du, *Closed-form formulas for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$*, Symmetry **15** (2023), no. 2, Article 323, 13 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15020323.
2. https://mathoverflow.net/a/439188.